# Fetching a formData via React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am writing a very dumb application using React Native / Flask but can't seem to be able to construct the formData. The formData.append function gives me this error:`Argument of type '{ uri: any; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'.`

This is how I'm fetching, the problem seems to be in the way the formDAta is being created, but I have tried pretty much everything and still doesn't work so I thought of asking here.

```
const ImagePickerScreen = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };

  const handleIsHotdog = async () => {
    if (!image) {
      alert("No image selected");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', {
        uri: image,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'selectedImage.jpg'
      });

      const response = await fetch('http://my endopoint here', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });
      const responseJson = await response.text();
      Alert.alert(
        'Result',
        responseJson,
        [
          { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
        ],
        { cancelable: false },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

And this is on the server-side:

```
@app.route("/process_image", methods=["POST"])
def classify_image():
    image = request.files["image"]
    image = PIL.Image.open(image)
    
    # Load the model
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('hotdog_model.h5')
    
    # Preprocess the image
    target_size = (224, 224)
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    # Use the model to make a prediction
    prediction = model.predict(image)

    # Return the result
    if prediction[0][0] > 0.5:
        return "Hotdog"
    else:
        return "Not Hotdog"
```

The server works when I do postman request (using formdata.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error: Android or iOS or both?

Comment: Both. It’s a typescript error so it doesn’t even let me run it.